# Index seek with coalesce

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have a table [MyTable] with a column [MyColumn] NVarchar(50). I have a nonclustered index on this column, now while running the below two queries:

```
SELECT  1
FROM    [MyTable] M
WHERE   M.[MyColumn] = @MyColumn

SELECT  1
FROM    [MyTable] M
WHERE   M.[MyColumn] = COALESCE(@MyColumn, M.[MyColumn] )
```

I noticed the first query is using *Index Seek (NonClustered)* and the second one is using *Index Scan (Non Clustered)*. May I know how will I make use of index seek with coalesce or isnull ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> May I know how will I make use of
>   index seek with coalesce or isnull ?

Perhaps not an answer to your question but you can have two different queries. One for the case where `@MyColumn is null` and one for the case where you want to use `@MyColumn` in the where clause.

```
IF @MyColumn IS NULL
BEGIN
  SELECT  1
  FROM    [MyTable] M
END  
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT  1
  FROM    [MyTable] M
  WHERE   M.[MyColumn] = @MyColumn
END
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't easy, since as Alex pointed out using the functions forces a scan, since the optimizer knows it needs to check every row.

What you CAN do is created a [**Computed Column**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) for  the result of your function, [and index that column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx).

There's not really a prettier way to get a seek.

**EDIT:**

In rereading your question, this may not be an option for you unless you rethink your logic.  You are integrating a variable into the function, and there is absolutely no way to index that.

**EDIT 2:**

Instead of your current logic, try something like:

```
...
WHERE (M.[MyColumn] = @MyColumn 
       OR @MyColumn IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using functions like `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` in the where clause is asking the server to search for the *results* of those functions - which are unknown until they are executed for every row in the resulting set, so there is no way for it to make use of an index.

To take full advantage of the index don't use functions in the WHERE clause, modify it with standard conditions e.g. `WHERE MyColumn = @MyColumn OR @MyColumn IS NULL`

Comment: Only that `MyColumn = @MyColumn OR @MyColumn IS NULL` will also lead to an index scan. ;-)

Comment: I ran "MyColumn = @MyColumn OR @MyColumn IS NULL" this too but unforunately same output it is using Index Scan (Non Clustered)

Comment: `OR` does not short circuit, it will check each row regardless.  If the optimizer knows it will need to check each row, it's just going to do a scan.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will use this query in a more complex one, possibly with`EXISTS`:

```
EXISTS 
( SELECT  1
  FROM    [MyTable] M
  WHERE   M.[MyColumn] = COALESCE(@MyColumn, M.[MyColumn] )
)
```

Try this instead:

```
EXISTS 
( SELECT  1
  FROM    [MyTable] M
  WHERE   M.[MyColumn] = @MyColumn
)
OR EXISTS
( SELECT  1
  FROM    [MyTable] M
  WHERE   @MyColumn IS NULL
)
```

---

Or this one:

```
CASE WHEN @MyColumn IS NULL
     THEN 1
     ELSE 
        ( SELECT  1
          FROM    [MyTable] M
          WHERE   M.[MyColumn] = @MyColumn
        )
END
```

Answer (score 0):

In the query with the coalesce clause the optimizer knows "MyColumn" is a range of values so it will decide to use a scan on the index.  The only method to use a seek when there is a non null variable passed in is to code two stored procs and call the appropiate one via logic testing of the variable.

If you have a situation as simple as your example and you wish to use an Index Seek when the variable is NOT NULL then you should code the query as :

```
If @MyColumn is NULL
Begin
    EXEC MyStoredProcWithMyColumn=Mycolumn
END
ELSE
Begin
    EXEC MyStoredProcWithMyColumn=Variable @MyColumn
END
```

after creating two stored procedures one which returns the data using the where clause with the variable and one with the where cluase for the column equal to itself.