# SQL Server : check if variable is Empty or NULL for WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, where-clause

When searching for a list of products, the `@SearchType` parameter is optional. If `@SearchType` is empty or `NULL` then it should return all products and not use the `WHERE` clause. Otherwise, if it passed `Equipment` it would then use that instead.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[psProducts] 
    (@SearchType varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        P.[ProductId],
        P.[ProductName],
        P.[ProductPrice],
        P.[Type]
    FROM [Product] P
    -- if @Searchtype is not null then use the where clause
    WHERE p.[Type] = @SearchType
END
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Just use

If @searchType is null means 'return the whole table' then use

```
WHERE p.[Type] = @SearchType OR @SearchType is NULL
```

If @searchType is an empty string means 'return the whole table' then use

```
WHERE p.[Type] = @SearchType OR @SearchType = ''
```

If @searchType is null or an empty string means 'return the whole table' then use

```
WHERE p.[Type] = @SearchType OR Coalesce(@SearchType,'') = ''
```

Comment: It is not working. It returns no results when I pass no parameter. The products page looks for a query string for type, if not, then sets the method parameter Type="". So, I believe the Stored proc might be looking for a SearchType ="" which returns no results. I want to return ALL results.

Comment: It's not working because you're passing an empty string. An empty string is not NULL!

Comment: @User970008 if that's the case then your question is wrong. There is a whole world of difference between NULL and an empty string.

Comment: @User970008 If you have multiple WHERE conditions, you'll want to you use paranthesis: `AND (p.[Type] = @SearchType OR Coalesce(@SearchType,'') = '')`

Answer (score 17):

If you don't want to pass the parameter when you don't want to search, then you should make the parameter optional instead of assuming that `''` and `NULL` are the same thing.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[psProducts] 
(
  @SearchType varchar(50) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT P.[ProductId]
  ,P.[ProductName]
  ,P.[ProductPrice]
  ,P.[Type]
  FROM dbo.[Product] AS P
  WHERE p.[Type] = COALESCE(NULLIF(@SearchType, ''), p.[Type])
  OPTION (RECOMPILE);
END
GO
```

Now if you pass `NULL`, an empty string (`''`), or leave out the parameter, the where clause will essentially be ignored.

I added `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to demonstrate that seeks *are* possible with the right parameter values and provided the index covers the query adequately, however a seek is very unlikely if the compilation occurred for `NULL` (whole table) or a parameter value that returned too many rows to make a seek worthwhile. Give it a try.

[image]

In reality, though, optional parameters that tend to lead to scans when they shouldn't should almost certainly be handled with with a combination of dynamic SQL and, for parameters where data skew can be an issue, `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. See my "kitchen sink" approach here, and give it a try:

- [An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)

Comment: Great answer! However I could not get this to use an Index Seek on p.[Type] (if an index was defined on it). It always does an Index Scan (compared to an Index Seek if querying p.[Type] = 'value' directly). Do you have any idea how to optimize the query further?

Comment: @Grimm It's probably for other reasons - usually a scan isn't happening simply because of syntax (e.g. how many rows match the type you're searching for, how many rows matched when you first ran the query, when you first ran your query did you specify a param or not, how many columns are in your index, how many columns are you asking for in your query?).

Comment: Unfortunately not - give it a try! There is a whole other threat complaining about this (I just searched stackoverflow to investigate this further). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186732/index-seek-with-coalesce

Comment: We all now that "... WHERE col IS NULL OR col = '' " runs significantly faster than " ... WHERE ISNULL(col, '') <> '' " I guess this is for the same reason - SQL Server evaluates the expression for every row when functions like ISNULL or COALESCE are involved.

Comment: Just found out that even an index hint won't avoid an Index Scan.

Comment: `We all now that "... WHERE col IS NULL OR col = '' " runs significantly faster than " ... WHERE ISNULL(col, '') <> '' "` - what evidence do you have of that?

Comment: Evidence: Own testing - again, give it a try (plus personal development experience over the years).

Comment: Yes, dynamic SQL seems to be the only way to force index seeks. But of course we all try to find ways to avoid that ...

Comment: @Grimm Updated my answer. I'd be careful to make gross generalizations about "this syntax is always faster than this other equivalent syntax" and "this pattern never yields a seek" because "always" and "never" are too easy to disprove. Also dynamic SQL is a perfectly fine solution to a lot of problems - don't avoid it just because it's dynamic SQL.

Comment: Mea culpa - you're right! I absolutely assumed that the recompile would not help, as I am testing and rewriting direct SQL SELECTs. The interesting thing is that SQL Server "falls back" to an index scan when you comment out the (Recompile) option again (without adjusting the parameter, just rerun).

Comment: Also interesting: a FORCESEEK hint gives an error message for the same query without option recompile but with the same parameter (for which an index scan would be executed).

Answer (score 6):

```
WHERE p.[Type] = isnull(@SearchType, p.[Type])
```

Comment: Not working. See above. It returns no results, I need to return all results instead.

Comment: It's not working because you're passing an empty string. An empty string is not NULL!

Answer (score 2):

Old post but worth a look for someone who stumbles upon like me

```
ISNULL(NULLIF(ColumnName, ' '), NULL) IS NOT NULL

ISNULL(NULLIF(ColumnName, ' '), NULL) IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use some dynamic query, you can use `LEN` . It will give false on both empty and null string. By this way you can implement the option parameter.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[psProducts] 
(@SearchType varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max) = N'
    SELECT 
        P.[ProductId],
        P.[ProductName],
        P.[ProductPrice],
        P.[Type]
    FROM [Product] P'
    -- if @Searchtype is not null then use the where clause
    SET @Query = CASE WHEN LEN(@SearchType) > 0 THEN @Query + ' WHERE p.[Type] = ' + ''''+ @SearchType + '''' ELSE @Query END   

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
    PRINT @Query
END
```

Answer (score 0):

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[psProducts]
(@SearchType varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
SELECT 
    P.[ProductId],
    P.[ProductName],
    P.[ProductPrice],
    P.[Type]
FROM [Product] P
-- if @Searchtype is not null then use the where clause
WHERE p.[Type] = @SearchType
```

END

Ans:

In above Case: you can use

Where (p.Type is null and @SearchType is null) or (p.Type is not null and p.Type = @SearchType)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).