# query builder laravel if var null or "" load all data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a var let's say `$var1`

I want to run it in query builder like this

```
DB::table('test')->join('... `many join here` ....')->where('testA', '=', '$var1')->get();
```

the problem is if `$var = ""` or `null` it's not return any data

I try to follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284164/sql-server-check-if-variable-is-empty-or-null-for-where-clause) @phill answer

but confused implemented in query builder laravel

---

@update

[image]

when i add `$get` in `3` it's not display anything

and when i check console it's error 500 (object of class can't be converted to string)

when i add `$get` in `2` it's can give result when `$var` not empty..but when `$var` empty it's error

where i'm missing?

Comment: i'm little bit confused. What do you want to achieve if the `var` is empty?

Comment: @SSuhat i want to load all data...default where will give no result because `$var` is empty

Comment: ah my bad i don't read the title carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
$var1 = "";
$q = DB::table('test')->join('... `many join here` ....');

$result = !isset($var1) ? $q : $q->where('testA', '=', $var1);
$result = $result->orderBy('column')->get();
 return $result;
```

You can change `empty` to `!isset` if you prefer using it.

Comment: i tried using this code..it's can load all data when `$var` empty` but when `$var` have value it's still load all data..not spesific value `where $var`

Comment: I've update my `where` query. I mistakenly put string instead of variable.

Comment: hmm i get a little error implement it in my script...wait a minute i will updalod it..maybe you can check

Comment: I've update my answer. Try `dd($var)` look what it gives you when you not fill it and fill it.

Comment: `$var` is undifined when empty i `dd()`

Comment: What if you fill it with value?

Comment: the value of var let say it's `S001`

Comment: What you fix? Can i know?

Comment: it's actually my bad...i misplace and mistype my real variabel `$suplier` with my example variabel `$var`